# UICollectionView image re-appears on cell

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I use the following code to add images from array to uicollectionview cell's.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *emoji = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
    emoji.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagePack objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    emoji.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:emoji];

    return cell;
}
```

When I scroll the UICollectionView down then scroll it up, the images reappears on top of each cell.. Lets say i have image 1 for cell 1, image 2 for cell 2, and so on. If i scroll down then up, in cell 1 i have image 1, and on top of image 1 is image 2.

It's messing up the images after i scroll, before scrolling looks normal.

Please any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because you are using the cell-recycling stuff, so when a cell is returned to you for re-use you should be removing (or reusing) any old imageView
try something like this..

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *emoji = nil;

      //try to find old imageView
     for (UIView *vw in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([vw isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class] ]){
          emoji = (UIImageView *)vw;
        }
      }

    if (emoji==nil){
   //we failed to find an imageView...

        emoji = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:emoji];
        //creating a UIImageView only if one is not already there
    }else{
    emoji.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

   emoji.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagePack objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; 
   emoji.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; 


    return cell; 

}
```